what are examples of low-frequency navigation receiver in an aircraft?
AIM 5-3-3 a. states when reports should be made to ATC or FSS. and 5-3-3 a. 1-(a) says "any loss in controlled airspace of VOR, TACAN, ADF, or low-frequency navigation receiver capability"
what are example of low-frequency navigation receiver that's in an aircraft? All I found using LF is AM radio, but is AM radio certified to be used in an aircraft?

AM radio is medium frequency (MF). ADF receivers are capable of receiving AM radio stations.

I recently found NDB frequency is from 180-535 kHz, which is LF navigation equipemnt.

The AIM excerpt you cite already lists ADF (which is the receiver for NDB ground stations), the last LF navigation system still in activity. Thus by "low-frequency navigation" AIM might refer to Loran-C, a system shut down between 2010 and 2015.
Before Loran-C, other long range navigation systems have been used: Omega, Decca, Soviet RSDN (Alpha) --perhaps still in use. They are collectively known as hyperbolic navigation systems for they compare the time of arrival (phase) of signals from different synchronized stations, and the locus of solutions for a pair of stations is an hyperbola. The current location is found by intersecting two hyperbolas.
Very low frequency (VLF) and low frequency (LF) waves propagate well on long distances, they are ducted by reflective ionosphere and ground, and can travel across continents and oceans (with areas of silence between hops). This mode of propagation totally disappears for VHF and shorter wavelengths.

Use of the radio spectrum by aviation.
